# UML One to Many Class Relationship

Tags: uml, lucidchart

I am very new to UML and am using Lucidchart to model some classes in java. I am trying to represent a one to many relationship where 1 artist will have many albums and each album will have 1 artist. Is this the correct way to model this relationship? [image: ERD]

**EDIT**

Thank you for your help. This is what I have come up with so far. I'm still a little confused about what else was said about the properties. Are the multiplicities and lines correct?

[image: UML]

Comment: Lucidchart offers several modeling notations. You didn't take the UML one. The notation you're showing corresponds to the ER (entity-relationship) language

Comment: This is getting better. Still some problems. Lose those list attributes, use property names at the ends of the associations, then reconsider some of your generalizations. E.g., not all `Band Members` and `Artists` are `Composers`. In real life, a `Person` can also be a `BandMember` in multiple `Bands`, which points out one reason why you shouldn't use generalizations for roles.

Comment: Some of the multiplicities are probably not right. E.g., An `Album` can have many `Artists` performing on it. An `Album` can have more than one `Band` playing on it. A `Song` can appear on many `Albums`. A `BandMember` can play different `Instruments` on various `Albums`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your diagram is incorrect as a UML diagram. I can tell because of the crow's foot on the end of the association.

To make your diagram correct:

- Change the crow's foot to a multiplicity of `0..*`
- Move the `albums` property to the `Album` end of the association (as you should never bury a list like this in UML--that's what associations represent!)
- Change the `Artist` end of the association to a multiplicity of `1`
- Name the property on the `Artist` end of the association (e.g., `artist`)
- Make a new class called `Song` (which is an actual concept with more information than a name, such as duration, composer, etc.)
- Make a new association between `Album` and `Song`, creating appropriate multiplicities and properties

Comment: To be fair, the diagram _is_ correct in the ER notation, it's just not UML

Comment: Although this was tagged as a UML question, I softened the wording a bit.

Comment: @JimL. Thank your for your help. I have updated my post above with more questions pertaining to your answer.